# Apache common CSV formatter: IOException: invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, opencsv, apache-commons-csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file using JakartaCommons-csv

**Sample input file**

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5
"Ryan, R"u"bianes","  dummy@gmail.com","29445","626","South delhi, Rohini 122001"
```

**Formatter**: CSVFormat.newFormat(',').withIgnoreEmptyLines().withQuote('"')
CSV_DELIMITER is ,

**Output**

1. Field1 value after CSV parsing should be : Ryan, R"u"bianes
2. Field5 value after CSV parsing should be : South delhi, Rohini 122001

**Exception:** Caused by: java.io.IOException: (line 2) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Comment: `"Ryan, R"u"bianes"` <-- you really need to escape the double quotes in your source data.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your file is not following the accepted standard for quoting in CSV files.  The correct way to represent a quote in a quoted string is by repeating the quote.  For example.

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5
"Ryan, R""u""bianes","  dummy@gmail.com","29445","626","South delhi, Rohini 122001"
```

If you restrict yourself to the standard form of CSV quoting, the Apache Commons CSV parser should work.

Unfortunately, it is not feasible to write a consistent parser for your variant format because there is no way disambiguate an embedded comma and a field separator if you need to represent a field containing "`Ryan R","baines`".

The rules for quoting in CSV files are set out in various places including [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2).

Comment: [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)  handles this, check my other answer

Comment: @stephen-c Is there a way we can skip this particular row and continue the processing for the next set of rows?

Comment: Looking at the Commons CSV parser code, I think the answer is no.

Comment: @stephen-c That was my hunch as well by looking at the code but it's a feature which should ideally have been there. Any suggested workaround. I am thinking of doing something like this
                          
    do {
    try {
    while (csvRecords.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord record = csvRecords.next();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception occurred while parsing one of the input record");
    }
    } while (csvRecords.hasNext());

Comment: It might work.  (Try it and see!!!)  But I doubt it.  I didn't notice any code to skip to the end of line before throwing the exception.

Comment: Yes it seems to partially work
@stephen-c Didn't followed the comment however. I guess what you mean is to do csvRecords.next(); inside catch block.

Issue: If i don't do "csvRecords.next(); inside catch block" then it resumes from the position the error occured in the same line.

Comment: Reviving this with 2 answers: 1. the parser will throw that error, but will keep processing next rows. 2. to avoid that error, double quotes should be escaped with \ as opposed to repeating quotes.

Comment: @Alexis - 1) The parser doesn't "keep processing".  An exception stops it.  What I think you are saying is that you can call `next()` again after catching the exception.  However, the javadoc doesn't specify whether this is supported or not ... or how well it will recover.  For example, what would happen with a CSV format where newlines can be embedded in a string.  "It works" is an incomplete and dubious answer.

Comment: 2) Well yes.  Various people have already pointed that out that the best solution is to do the quoting as per the spec.

Comment: Either way ... if you want to write an answer or start a (beta) discussion ... do that.  But there's no need to "revive" this answer.  The answer is not dead ... and StackOverflow answer comments are not intended for discussions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the quotes are not properly escaped. Your parser doesn't handle that. Try [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as this is the only parser for java I know  that can handle unescaped quotes inside a quoted value. It is also 4 times faster than Commons CSV. Try this code:

```
    //configure the parser to handle your situation
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //uses first line as headers
    settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);
    settings.trimQuotedValues(true); //trim whitespace around values in quotes

    //create the parser
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    String input = "" +
            "Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5\n" +
            "\"Ryan, R\"u\"bianes\",\"  dummy@gmail.com\",\"29445\",\"626\",\"South delhi, Rohini 122001\"";

    //parse your input
    List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input));

    //print the parsed values
    for(String[] row : rows){
        for(String value : row){
            System.out.println('[' + value + ']');
        }
        System.out.println("-----");
    }
```

This will print:

```
[Ryan, R"u"bianes]
[dummy@gmail.com]
[29445]
[626]
[South delhi, Rohini 122001]
-----
```

Hope it helps.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library, it's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)